# Fixed size html text input area - doesn't allow more text beyond limit defined by boundary

Tags: javascript, css, html, textarea

I'd like to have a fixed line text area which doesn't allow the user to type in more text beyond the fixed number of lines (and max width). Is this possible?

My current css styling for  is this:

```
.area-style {
    resize: none;
    width: 324px;
    height: 200px;
    max-height:200px;
    max-width:324px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But it is still possible to continue entering text beyond the 'bottom' (the text gets pushed up within the textarea) - this happens in Chrome and Firefox at least. I want the textarea to just not allow any more text to be entered beyond that point, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to limit the number of characters inserted in a text area.

```
<textarea maxlength="400"> </textarea>
```

The maxlength attribute is new for the  tag in HTML5. The browsers that support textlength attribute are :
Chrome - yes
IE - 10.0
Firefox - 4.0
Safari - yes

Comment: Thanks, that certainly helps, don't know why that didn't pop up on my research. It still allows the user to hit 'return' though within textarea which takes it beyond the 4 lines. I like to limit input to the total visual area regardless.

Answer (score 0):

In html5 you can add a maxlenght attribute to fix the the maximum number of characters allowed in the text area.

```
<textarea class="area-style" maxlength="200"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly helps, don't know why that didn't pop up on my research. It still allows the user to hit 'return' though within textarea which takes it beyond the 4 lines. I like to limit input to the total visual area regardless.